# PowerShell Script for creating AD Users - OU subdirectories

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I'm working on a PowerShell Script to create users in Active Directory.

```
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Start1234" -AsPlainText -Force

New-ADUser -Name "Markus Xidl" `
       -SamAccountName "m.xidl" `
       -Path "ou=Kunde\Benutzer\Mitarbeiter,dc=test,dc=local" `
       -Enabled $true `
       -AccountPassword $pwd
```

Within my Active Directory, I have a OU called `Kunde` and within that OU another OU called `Mitarbeiter`.
The script does not work. It does work, if I remove the `Mitarbeiter` OU, but then I'd have to  move the Users by hand. What is the correct way to specify this path so the script can work correctly?

[image]

Comment: Don't use `$pwd` as self-defined variable name because it is an [automatic variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#pwd) in PowerShell. Choose a different name for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "-Path" must be `OU=Mitarbeiter,OU=Benutzer,OU=Kunde,DC=phil,DC=local` because the directory tree in Active Directory must be from the deepest level up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your "-Path" to "ou=Kunde,ou=Benutzer,ou=Mitarbeiter,dc=test,dc=local" `

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. I get this error message: `New-ADUser : Der Server kann die Anforderung nicht ausführen` Which translates to `The server cannot execute this task`

Comment: I made an error with which way to list the OU's, it should be this way 

$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Start1234" -AsPlainText -Force

New-ADUser -Name "Jim Bob" `
       -SamAccountName "J.bob" `
       -Path "OU=Mitarbeiter,OU=Benutzer,OU=Kundle,DC=starship,DC=com" `
       -Enabled $true `
       -AccountPassword $pwd

Comment: Seconds before you posted it, I figured it out by trail and error. Thanks anyway